# How do I globally change the longtable font size?

Tags: memoir, rmarkdown

I am using `R Markdown` and `Latex` with `memoir` to compile a book to pdf. There are tables in the book that are too wide and go into the margins. Checking the compiled `.tex` file I can see that the conversion from markdown is to `longtable`. How do I globally change the font size so that the tables fit properly?

Comment: You can nest the longtable in a group, and type something like`\footnotesize` at the beginning of the group. Also, don't forget another useful tool to make a table fit between margins conists in reducing the value of `\tabcolsep`  (default is 6pt).

Comment: Thank you @Bernard but I need to do this in one place for the whole book.

Comment: Do you mean all your longtables have  this problem?  In this case, you can use in the preamble `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{…}`.

Comment: why are your tables too wide? you don't have to use `llll` columns, if your columns use `p{3cm}` or whatever the tables are a known width and you should know in advance they fit within the page width.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If the table is exported from R markdown, the user cannot set the width of columns (only can make  `l`, `c` and  `r` aligns),   but it is possible use another types of tabulars with  (a)  a R chunk, using data frames formatted with  xtable or kable R functions or (b) make a table float directly in LaTeX code.

Comment: @Fran Yes. In addition this was a book written in plain markdown and I was asked to help convert it to Latex. R Markdown was the easiest route. I will try the suggestions from Bernard when I get a bit of time.

Comment: @Bernard `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\tiny}` did it! Thanks! Only problem is that it did not affect inline code that remained large and looks weird. Any ideas on that? Also post it as an answer if you want to I can accept it 

Comment: I don't  see what you mean with `inline code`. Can you explain?

Comment: @Bernard I mean that one of the columns has code snippets using the backtick syntax in markdown which is translated to tex as `\passthrough{\lstinline!-5.squared!}` for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know  nothing about markdown. Just in case, there also exists   `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` command. Unrelated: I wouldn't use `\tiny` for a whole table, it would make it almost unreadable For me, the minimum size is `scriptsize`, or preferably, `footnotesize`.

Comment: @Bernard Yes it is tricky. Some tables still don't fit and you are right about `\tiny` being too small. I think part of the issue is that the long column titles do not wrap and cause the columns to be really wide. It is a book in Greek and we tend to have long words...

Comment: To break column heads you can use the `makecell` package, which enables line-breaking (by hand) in standard cells. In particular, the `\thead` command uses `\footnotesize`  by default for its contents

Comment: @Dionysis Indeed markdown is the easiest route for simple tables, but in many cases insufficient, and then, type directly in LaTeX is not a better solution, is the solution (full stop) But if you are speaking of show data that are already in some R code in the book, both approaches are usually wrong.